# secure user authentication script electron

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, encryption, electron

I am new to developing and I am trying to create an app that is a SaaS. I am using `electron` to make this app. I use `cryptlex` to authenticate licenses. Is there any way to secure this step of the process? 
As electron uses `.js` files to work, my authentification file is `.js`also, and I don't want someone to figure out how my authentification process works. and go around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already finished working on this project. There is no way of securing client side js code. I used bytenode and obfuscator instead